# Outlook on Lumia 830 and Windows 10 insider

Tags: insider-preview, outlook

When starting Outlook, the first mail I click, open immediately, if I go to the next, also works ok, however (and after a few seconds) if I pick a random one, the app get stuck waiting forever with the dots dancing on top and close itself.

Upon reopening Outlook, (sometimes) the splash shows up for a few seconds and close, opening again, work for some time.

Is there any new or alternative version to replace Outlook?
Is this a known issue?

Comment: Which email provider do you use?

Comment: I'm using Exchange Server 2010, Gmail, Hotmail, Outlook.com. I assume that when selecting one the others are 'dormant' (ie not using resources). The problem is the same with all of them. 
Sometimes, replies and forwards, looks like are sent but never arrives.

Comment: Do you have a lot of emails? On my Lumia 830 outlook is running fine but i use gmail only so i have no experience with multiple accounts in outlook.

Comment: Outlook and Exchange are quite smart on handling large number of mails, (usually) only the headers are transmitted and upon opening the mail is pulled from the source. Before W10, this was not and issue.

Comment: Is the app and your phone up to date?

Comment: A while ago, with Windows 10, Microsoft started the idea of `Windows as a Service`, basically, the user is not anymore controlling updates, Microsoft is; you can only determine at what time to reboot :). So, answering your question of course yes, is updated.
I have Windows-Phone(s) since inception a few years ago and this is the first buggy experience. 
I think that the CPU on the 830 is not powerful enough and maybe grab a new 950 XL is the fix.